# Probability and the physical world

Tags: probability

I have just started learning the theory of probability, and got the following question while reading some examples presented in my textbook.

The [Bertrand paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)) shows that “probabilities may not be well defined if the mechanism or method that produces the random variable is not clearly defined.” However, in some cases, I find that there is a “chosen” method, especially for the problems that has a  physical background.

To illustrate, consider the [Buffon’s needle problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle_problem) (Let’s stick to the case of short needles). This is solved by assuming both the distance between the center of the needle and the border of strips and the orientation of the needle are randomly chosen under uniform probability density. Plus, several experiments somehow “proved” that this method is correct.

However, I believe that there are different methods that produce different problem density, and thereby give another answer (For example, consider that the orientation is affected by the distance). Although these methods may seem ridiculous, I couldn’t find a plausible explanation to reject them. Why the needles are actually placed in the way that the first method says?

In general, my questions is:

> How can we know that we are using the right method when the choices are arbitrary?

or:

> How can we know that we are using the method that explains the real world physics?

Comment: In Probability like in Physics, Biology, etc... you are not sure a priori that the model you propose fits the observed reality (for example by comparing random simulations and theoretical computations). It has been by numerous ways and backs that some models have been confirmed as good/efficient/well fitting and - very important - allowing to anticipate new results.

Answer (score 1):

Symmetry is your friend (if the physical reality can be made to satisfy that symmetry).  Thus we try to set up the needle experiment so there is no "preferred" direction for the needle, resulting in the density being constant with respect to the angle $\theta$.  This might not be the case if the needle was a magnet (affected by the earth's magnetic field) or if the surface you're dropping it on was corrugated.  Translation invariance is not going to happen exactly, but we can try to make it approximately the case by dropping the needle from a considerable height.